# Isolating text from photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

how do I isolate text - I need to colour the world map but I keep losing the text (the names of areas) as I colour in the map

Comment: Can you tell me what the image is (link, picture, google search, etc)

Comment: Please include screenshots and if possible a step by step what you are doing that is not working/causing problems. It's unclear what exactly you are trying to achieve at the moment.

Comment: If this was "text", then it would live in a separate layer in your Photoshop document, and you'd have a hard time accidentally  *erasing* it (you'd probably just draw in a layer higher than the text). So I'm guessing you do NOT have "text" - but just pixels which look like text.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be to use the  Magic Wand Tool and select each "text" from your map. With the text selected you can create a new layer ( Ctrl+ J on Windows). You can then safely paint your map without affecting the text. However, it will not look very good so I suggest another option. Why don't you just remember all the names and add them later using your Type Tool? You can find a font that matches the original or even come with a new and better one.

Cheers!